Google Service to Recognize Text from Speech (for Angular or JS)
I am trying to find a Google service to recognize a text from speech. Is there a solution to do it in the frontend. I am using Angular and would like to do everything in the frontend without backend
I know Azure has Cognitive Services for this and they only work in the frontend. But for some reason I need to use only Google services
Could you help me to find a service that will work on the frontend only by using subscription key or something?
Thanks
I know Azure has Cognitive Services for this and they only work in the frontend. But for some reason I need to use only Google services
